# Showing that the series of function converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that the following series of functions converges uniformly on any bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(x^2+n)}{n^2}$$

I was trying to solve this using Weierstrass M-test. As of my understanding, it says that
$\sum_{}f_n(x)$ converges uniformly if $|f_n(x)| \le M_n(x)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n(x)$ converges.

Here is my attempt:

Let $[a,b]$ be the bounded subset, then $x \le b.$ Thus $$|f_n(x)| = \left|\frac{(-1)^n(x^2+n)}{n^2}\right| = \frac{(x^2+n)}{n^2} \le \frac{(b^2+n)}{n^2}$$

Thus $|f_n(x)| \le M_n$ where $M_n = \frac{(b^2+n)}{n^2}$.

Now we need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n(x)$ converges. This is where I am stuck since $\sum_{}M_n$ will diverge. Not sure how to change $M_n$ so that Weierstrass M-test works.

Comment: If you get rid of the $(-1)^n$ then the series is not uniformly convergent anymore (it does not even converge pointwise). That $(-1)^n$ is essential, in the sense that it allows you to consider convergence by [Leibniz test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). Try to use the estimate of the remainder given by Leibniz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n(x)= \frac{(x^2+n)}{n^2}$. For any $x \in \mathbb R$, $a_n(x)$ is positive and a decreasing sequence. Hence according to [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), your have

$$\lvert S_n(x) - S(x) \rvert \le a_{n+1}(x)$$ where $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k(x)$ and $S(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(x)$. From there, it is easy to prove that $\sum a_n(x)$ converges uniformly on any bounded subset of $\mathbb R$.